# Numpy and Python

Tags: python, numpy

I created a python .py with some sort methods. I'm using numpy so that I can use real arrays. My question is when I go to submit this file to my teacher, is there a dll or something i can include so that he will be able to run the program or will he have to install numpy himself? Is the .py file the only file I should have to commit? Thanks in advance for any tips.

```
   import numpy as np
```

Comment: http://www.logix4u.net/component/content/article/27-tutorials/44-how-to-create-windows-executable-exe-from-python-script

Comment: Do you actually need numpy? I would rather submit a self-contained example (that is, only using Python core and stdlib).

Comment: yea its a pain working with arrays tho. numpy makes it a million times easier for arrays and I can use the built in min max average and sort for some of my methods

Comment: @ZoZo123 it seems py2exe only wants to work with python vs2.6, I have 3.2, does this sound right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They need to install numpy from http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/ - just list this as a requrirement in the comments

Answer (score 0):

if you're using *nix(linux or unix) system, you can use this command to let your teacher to install the numpy module : `apt-get install python-numpy`

Comment: This will not work if the teacher is using redhat, as this is for debian-based systems (like ubuntu). It will also not work on any flavor of unix.